# Missing Dimension members

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas

I have a cube which used to throw an error when processing.
This was because the fact table had rows which had empty values.And there was no corresponding row in the dimension tables having an empty values.

What I did was introduce a default row in all the dimension tables.

As a result the cube got processed without any error.
But the problem arose with the members in the date dimensions.
Some of the members were just missing when the cube was re processed.

I tried looking into the fact table but the data seems fine.
If the queries for the dimension tables are run seperately, all the members are present.

Comment: I read the narrative but couldn't figure out what the question you are asking is?

Comment: The question is any idea why this is happening? and where should i look into?

Answer (score 0):

This issue got solved. What i did was reload the database and then process the cube again. Surprisingly all the members are now visible.